# How Access Database Values Using Array In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a web site. So , I have stored data in the database. Now I want to view data from two different tables. Then I tried a method like below. But , it gives me this error -

```
Trying to get property 'firstname' of non-object (View: D:\wamp64\www\cheapfares\resources\views\invoices\des.blade.php)
```

But , clearly firstname is in the database table.

How can I Fix this ??

Controller page. ( InvoicesController.blade.php )

```
public function userinvoice($terms = '',$invoiceNo = '')
    {

        $invoice = Invoice::where('invoicereference', $invoiceNo)->get()->first();

        $tr = DB::table('termsandconditions')
            ->where('topic', $terms)->get()->first();

        $twoar = [];
        $twoar['inv'] = $invoice;
        $twoar['trms'] = $tr;

        return view('invoices.des', ['twoar' => $twoar]);

    }
```

View page. ( des.blade.php )

```
{{$twoar['inv']->firstname}}

{{$twoar['trms']->topic}}
```

Route.

```
Route::get('/invoice/adminuser-invoice/{invoiceno}', [
    'uses' => 'InvoicesController@adminuserinvoice',
    'as' => 'invoice.adminuser'
]);
```

Comment: directly use `->first()` without `->get()`...

Comment: @dekts - I tried like this invoice = Invoice::where('invoicereference', $invoiceNo)->first();

        $tr = DB::table('termsandconditions')
            ->where('topic', $terms)->first();.. But , again same error..

Comment: what is result of : `$invoice = Invoice::where('invoicereference', $invoiceNo)->get()->first();
    dd($invoice->toArray());`

Comment: crap , it shows me null..

Comment: so It probably does not return a record from database

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi - Then How can I Fix it ??

Comment: If you have a record with  `ID` = 1, run this query :‌‍‍` $invoice = Invoice::where('id', 1)->get()->first();
    dd($invoice->toArray());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173191/discussion-between-alihossein-shahabi-and-amithash).

Answer (score 0):

Although casting the response to Array might be a suitable solution, the cause of your exception most likely lies in not having a valid entry in the database.

You can improve your code like this to mitigate that:

```
public function userinvoice($terms, $invoiceNo)
{
    // Load invoice, or throw ModelNotFoundException/404 without valid entries.
    $invoice = Invoice::where('invoicereference', $invoiceNo)->firstOrFail();

    // load the terms.
    $terms = DB::table('termsandconditions')
        ->where('topic', $terms)->first();


    return view('invoices.des', compact('invoice', 'terms'));

}
```

In this example I made `$terms` and `$invoiceNo` obligated arguments in the route. To ensure the query will provide proper results. In addition an Invoice entry is now required with `firstOrFail()`, the terms is optional. Instead of assigning both variables to an array, I'm sending them both to the view so you can assert their value properly without cluttering using array key access.

Your view:

```
{{$invoice->firstname}}

{{$terms->topic}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
public function userinvoice($terms = '',$invoiceNo = '')
{

    $invoice = Invoice::where('invoicereference', $invoiceNo)->get()->first();

    $tr = DB::table('termsandconditions')
        ->where('topic', $terms)->get()->first();



    return view('invoices.des', ['tr'=>$tr,'invoice'=>$invoice]); //Directly pass the mulitple values into  the view


}
```

And your  view page like this:

```
 {{$invoice->firstname}}
   {{$tr->topic}}
```

Its may help for you friend.